# Get active Github runner working directory or name

Tags: github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have self-hosted macOS runner `[self-hosted, some_label]` which have 3 runners in it:
`runner_1`, `runner_2`, `runner_3`.
One of the step of the job in my GHA is running tests:

```
name: Run tests
run: ./gradlew -- info :app:connectedCheck
```

After the job is done, I want to extract .xml file

```
Name: Upload res
uses: actions:upload-artifact@v3
with:
  name: Results
  path: Users/User1/github-runners/runner...
```

And there is a problem - I don't know which runner just have performed a previous step of the job.
It can be `runner_1` or `runner_3`, so i can't set precise path to .xml file which was generated in this runner `_work` folder

```
_work/android/.../outputs/android-testResults/connected/*.xml
```

Is there are any way to get active runner directory or something similar which will help to ID active runner directory ?
For example :

```
Users/User1/github-runners/runner-1...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [`github.workspace`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) and [`runner`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#runner-context) context.